# keystonejs display select option depending on choosing another select option

Tags: node.js, keystonejs

I'm trying in keystone.js app model to choose from select option what is related to what the user have chosen in another select option ..
so he will choose from the first , the second select option should have data related only to the first selected option .. 
I hope someone can help me
thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the dependsOn option.

Example..

```
type: { type: Types.Select, options: ['TypeOne','TypeTwo','TypeThree TypeFour' ], initial: true },

something: { type: Types.Text, dependsOn: { type: 'TypeThree' }, initial: true },
```

Example With Relationship - You can follow the logic showing that certain fields show up only if the dependsOn criteria is matched.

```
Adjustment.add({
type: { type: Types.Select, options: ['Booking','Shipment','Warehouse','Inventory' ], initial: true },
sku: { type: Types.Text, initial: true },
quantity: { type: Types.Number, initial: true, width: 'short' },
keyID: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Order', dependsOn: { type: 'Booking' }, initial: true },
bookingID: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Booking', dependsOn: { type: 'Booking' }, initial: true },
warehouse: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Warehouse', dependsOn: { type: 'Warehouse' }, initial: true },
shipmentID: { type: Types.Text, dependsOn: { type: 'Shipment' }, initial: true },
```

});

Comment: but I'm trying to make the options to be dynamic by using Types:relationships and ref to a model .... this is the trick i I'm facing

Comment: I updated my original answer to include an example with dependsOn being used with Relationships.

Comment: is it possible that the options data is from the database ?